# check files in one directory(s) if are present in other(s) and then execute copy

Tags: shell, macos

I have 'a1..a2..a3..' directories with lots of files.
So I want to check if any of files IS NOT in directories 'b1..b2..b3..'.
If it isn't, then this is interesting file for me. So would be good to move it somewhere else.

Also I don't want to depend on filenames, but file contents or md5.

I tried fdupes, but it show duplicates; and can't figure out the rest.

(because of the bash tag: I'd prefer a bash answer, thanks for help).

Comment: You don't have a [tag:bash] tag. Was it intended?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Title says "copy" but question says "move". Please be consistent

Comment: Do you really have directories named `a1`, `b1`, and `a2`, `b2`, etc. or are these placeholders? If they're placeholders how should we derive `bN` from `aN`?

Comment: Please do not respond in the comments. [Edit] your question to include extra information as if you'd provided it in the first place